# Win32: Forward child message to parent - return value is different

Tags: c, winapi, sendmessage

I have dialog created using `CreateDialogParam`. It has only a single `ListView` child control. In the dialog `WM_INITDIALOG` message handler, I subclass the `ListView` to customize header redrawing.

Now I want to prevent the user from resizing the `ListView` column (header) and, to do this, I just need to handle the `HDN_BEGINTRACKA` notification message in the `ListView`'s `WndProc`, like below:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        if ((((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA)
            || (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW))
            return TRUE; // to disable column resizing
    }
```

This works OK; but, for some reason I want to handle this message in the parent (dialog) procedure. So, I forward this message to that parent as below:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            if ((((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA)
                || (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW)) 
            {
                BOOL b = FALSE;
                HWND hParent = GetRealParent(hwnd);
                if (hParent) b = SendMessage(hParent, msg, wParam, lParam);
                return b; // to disable column resizing return TRUE;
            }
        }
        break;
```

The message is sent OK but, even though I return `TRUE` from the dialog procedure, here in the `ListView` procedure, the return value of the `SendMessage` call is `FALSE`.

In the dialog procedure, the code is as below:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        if ((((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA)
            || (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW))
            return TRUE;
    }
```

So, my question is why directly sending (forwarding) the `WM_NOTIFY` message to the parent returns a different result, or simply just doesn't work?

> Edit :-

In the past, I have faced the same problem; to solve it, I tried a user-defined message, like:

```
#define UWM_WM_NOTIFY (WM_APP + 7)
```

and use that with `SendMessage` to communicate between child and parent, or between any other dialogs. But it also fails to get proper return values.

So, I am using `SendMessage` as follow:

```
BOOL b = FALSE;
SendMessageA(hDlg, UWM_ANY_WM, 0, (LPARAM) &b);
return b;
```

Sending address of variable as `LPARAM` to get return value. Is there any better way to do this. Or Why `SendMessageA` return value is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-notify) for the `WM_NOTIFY` message<sup>1</sup>:

> If the message handler is in a dialog box procedure, you must use the
> `SetWindowLong` function with `DWL_MSGRESULT` to set a return value.

So, using the more up-to-date `SetWindowLongPtr` function, your parent (dialog box) handling for the `WM_NOTIFY` message should look something like this:

```c
case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        if ((((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA)
            || (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW))
        {
            SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, TRUE); // hWnd is dialog's HWND
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Also note that your handler should continue to return `TRUE`, as noted in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga):

> If you use `SetWindowLong` with the `DWL_MSGRESULT` index to set the
> return value for a message processed by a dialog procedure, you should
> return `TRUE` directly afterward. Otherwise, if you call any function
> that results in your dialog procedure receiving a window message, the
> nested window message could overwrite the return value you set using
> `DWL_MSGRESULT`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, you need to use the outlined mechanism to set the return value for *(almost) any* message handled by a dialog procedure, as nicely described in [this blog by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031107-00/?p=41923).

Comment: Thanks for Answer. it is really helpful. But Still I am in confusion as you can see, I edited my question to correct the mistake. As User define message did not solve the problem but I used `LPARAM` to get the return value. The problem seems to not just with `WM_NOTIFY` message but with every message.

Comment: @vkchavda: Indeed, the `DWL_MSGRESULT` is used for the return of any message from a dialog procedure. The documentation link in `WM_NOTIFY` is because that is a notable message used in dialogs that returns a value.

Comment: @rodrigo - Yes, indeed. See my edit and Raymond's linked blog.